# Jenkins CLI get test result

Tags: command-line, jenkins, command-line-interface

I am trying to find out if there is a command in the Jenkin's CLI, that provides you with an xml, txt, html or some file with test results from a job that was just executed. Does any one know of such command or way to do this?
The reason I'm asking is that I'm creating a job from an xml file via Jenkin's CLI. Then, I'm executing the job I just created and once the job is complete, I'd like to use a command and get the test results.

Thank you in advanced
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save the results of your test as artifact, and download it, as the url is known to be something like `http://jenkins.yourcompany.com/job/yourjob/buildId/artifact/testResults.xml`

Comment: That is what I was looking for, except that there would be a lot of parsing to do. Thanks!

Comment: There is a jenkins-client project on GitHub to help with it.   And maybe use Jackson2XmlToJson to make parsing easier in json format.